Endogenous interaction terms in Probit and robust standard errors
I'm using Probit model for an endogenous independent variable X1, and I've created interaction terms with the independent variable (see equation below). I'm using cross-sectional data.
Y= X1 + X2 + X3 + X1*X2 + X1*X3 +constant
By reviewing other posts, I realised that I cannot use ivprobit (in Stata) because the interaction terms are also endogenous. But I'm not sure if my method works, here's what I did:
regress X1 Z1 X2 X3
estimate X1_hat, xb
gen X1X2_hat = X1_hat * X2
gen X1X3_hat = X1_hat * X3
probit Y X1_hat X2 X3 X1X2_hat X1X3_hat
Z1 is the instrument for X1.
My questions are:

Are these commands correct? If so, how can I do robust standard errors on the basis of these?
If they are not correct, what commands can I use to run the regression?

Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

eprobit can handle endogenous x exogenous variable interactions.
